# Transform Java Library to JavaScript Library

Tags: java, javascript

If I have implemented a Java Library (that offers certain functionality), could I transform this into a JavaScript library, such that the same functionality can be offered?
I know this may be an ask, but, I was wondering if there are frameworks existing that help in this?

Comment: It depends on what your library does. What does it do?

Comment: @Andrew it mainly polls web-services, put data into the DB. But it does involve many external libraries to handle data conversion, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general this is not possible, Java and JavaScript are more or less completely different languages.

However there are a couple of Java to JavaScript translators that you can try. [Java2Script](http://j2s.sourceforge.net/) is one such tool. Apparently the Google Web Toolkit (GWT) does this as well. [Source](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/java_to_javascript.html).

Answer (score 1):

While you could probably do some sort of conversion, it's important to note that  Java and JavaScript, while similarly named, are not at all related.  Unfortunately, I think you'll be hard pressed to find a framework or system that does a good job converting one to the other. :(